# Very simple SQL-Query times out on azure sql database with small table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an azure sql db. It's a 'Standard S0 10DTU' instance. i know this is not great for performance, but i don't think what i see can be explained by the 10 DTU only. The db has almost no traffic, as it is only used for logging our nightly build results. When the tests are not running, nobody is using the db, apart from the query that fails.

The query is this "select top(10) * from db-name where id=ID". (ID beeing a variable of type int.) There are only 2500 records in the table. Aprox.5 match.

The first query attempt always times out. (timeout is thirty seconds). the 2nd of 3rd query, when done from the azure-db web-interface in azure, will take from 4-8 seconds. (which is *quite* long for 2500 records and an "int" compare). When the query is done from my c# app, it will sometimes work after several atempts, but mostly time out.

i have lots of stuff in S0/10DTU databases and i don't have any other problems - only with that specific query in that table.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

### Here is the actual code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SelectConnectionForm.ConnectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   var command = new SqlCommand( "SELECT TOP(10) CAST(severity AS int )AS severity,text FROM [dbo].[ItemReports] WHERE idItem=" +
                  testcase.Id, connection);
   var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
               var node = (string) reader["text"]);
      // Do Stuff with node    
   }

   reader.Close();
   connection.Close();
}
```

// "testcase.id" is an "int".

Comment: As you state that only 5 rows match, I assume therefore that you have a case sensitive collation, and thus have 2 columns, one called `id` and the other `ID`; even if it is case sensitive it's not a great idea to have 2 columns with the same name in different cases as it can be very confusing. What index(es) do you have on your table? Do you have one that is on both `id` and `ID` and `INCLUDE`s all the other columns from your table? Also, if there *are* only 5 rows that match, why the `TOP (10)` with no `ORDER BY`?

Comment: No, ID was meant to be a variable like "id=X", where X ist an integer. i don't have 2 columns with the same name, although even if i had, this would have nothing to do with my problem, would it? the id column has an index. Also: Only 5 rows match with that given example. what i meant was "very few rows, like 5, match". Sometimes it might be more than 5.

Comment: So `select top(10) * from db-name where id=ID` isn't actually the query you have? So what *is* the query?

Comment: If the query is simple and the table small there won't be any timeouts, even if `ID` isn't indexed. Unless some other action has taken long-lived locks on the table due to a long lived transaction. What you posted isn't a valid SQL query though. Post the actual query.

Comment: On the other hand, if ID isn't indexed and some other transaction has taken locks on some rows, even a SELECT will have to wait until that transaction ends. Without indexes, SELECT will have to scan all table rows and will get blocked by the rows that are being updated. That's a design problem, not a SQL problem. Transactions aren't meant to be long-lived

Comment: Does your logging code keep a single long-lived transaction open while writing? Or does the reading application keep a connection open for long? That could easily cause these problems on any database. Database logging systems batch records to avoid such problems and improve performance. Another option is to use SNAPSHOT isolation to read the existing data even while another connection writes to the table.

Comment: I don't have any transactions at all. Not while writing to the table, neither while reading. The reading application does not have a long-lived connection. There is no other connection to the database (as long as azure doesn't create any all by itself) while the reading application is reading.

Comment: I just cleared the table, only one record remained. Connected using SSMS, and did the following select: 

SELECT TOP (1000) [idItem],[severity],[text] FROM [dbo].[ItemReports]

Nobody else is connected to the database. The select tool 2 minutes an 8 seconds. There are other tables in that database where a 'select *' takes <1sec. Something must be wrong with that table, but what?

Comment: I dropped and recreated the table and the problem went away. I would still like to know what my be causing problems like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So someone somewhere else mentioned a "High water mark problem". I could not find any recent documentation concerning this. However, my table did indeed have a lot of writes and deletes (> 16.000.000, as it were). I assume, this is what 'high water mark' refers to.

What i did was drop and recreate the table and the problem went away.